# Can PHP variables be only the $ sign?

Tags: php

This is in some generated vendor code and I can't seem to figure out what it does. Can variables be named just $? Is $this->_ valid syntax?

```
public function __construct( $ = null )
{
           parent::__construct();
           $this->_ = $;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If you try to assign `$` a value you get an error.

At a guess, your code was generated by a function that takes a parameter which was empty, something like:

```
function generatePHPFile($name) {
  str = "public function __construct( $" . $name . "= null )";
  // write str to something.php
}

generatePHPFile("");
```

Although `$this->_` is valid I suspect it again was supposed to have that parameter, so `$this->_myobj` for example

Answer (score 0):

Based on [php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php): "A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores."

"any number" is 0 or more, so `$this->_` or `$_` are valid variables, but `$` alone is not.